# Ionic Caching not working

Tags: caching, ionic-framework

I'm developing an app using Ionic, but caching isn't working as expected.
Every time I switch from `root.home.notifs` to `root.home.chats` the `chats` view is refreshed (its controller is reinitialized).

I've 2 tabs:

```
  <ion-footer-bar>
    <ion-tabs class="tab-bottom tabs-striped">
      <ion-tab icon="ion-ios-chatboxes-outline" ui-sref="root.home.chats">
      </ion-tab>
      <ion-tab icon="ion-ios-heart-outline" ui-sref="root.home.notifs">
      </ion-tab>
    </ion-tabs>
  </ion-footer-bar>
```

And these states (my controllers are empty):

```
.state('root.home', {
  abstract: true,
  cache : true,
  url: '/home',
  templateUrl: 'components/home/templates/home.html'
})
.state('root.home.chats', {
  url: '/chats',
  cache : true,
  controller: 'ChatCtrl',
  templateUrl: 'components/home/templates/home.chats.html'
})
.state('root.home.notifs', {
  url: '/notifs',
  cache : true,
  controller: 'NotifCtrl',
  templateUrl: 'components/home/templates/home.notifs.html'
})
```

Every view has `cache-view="true"` and I've configured the cache this way `$ionicConfigProvider.views.maxCache(100)`

**NOTE:** I've noticed that this error depends on which state I navigate to first. There's an auth system that calls `$state.$go('root.home.notifs')`. Changing this changes which view is cached correctly

Any tip on how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this to cache the forward view `$ionicConfigProvider.views.forwardCache(true);`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.state('root.home', {
  abstract: true,
  cache : true,
  url: '/home',
  templateUrl: 'components/home/templates/home.html'
})
.state('root.home.chats', {
  url: '/chats',
 cache : true,
  controller: 'ChatCtrl',
  templateUrl: 'components/home/templates/home.chats.html'
})
.state('root.home.notifs', {
  url: '/notifs',
 cache : true,
  controller: 'NotifCtrl',
  templateUrl: 'components/home/templates/home.notifs.html'
})
```

Comment: Done, but I still have the same problem

Comment: I think problem in chache-view="true" use this: cache-view="false"

Comment: `cache-view="true"` is used to tell ionic to cache a view, that is what I want to achieve. Anyway, tried `cache-view="false"` but it doesn't work

Comment: Sorry it's my mistake, i mean your spelling was wrong chache-view="true", true is right

Answer (score -1):

Simply You can use cache-view in HTML.No need to use it on controller.
If You want to Refresh your page then use `<ion-view title="Dashboard" cache-view="false">` .
But if You want to cache ur page then put `<ion-view title="Dashboard" cache-view="true">`or simply `<ion-view title="Dashboard">`

Comment: If anyone put -1 on my answer then explain the reason. I have already done this and it is wrong .

Comment: The reason why I downvoted is because I've written in the answer that I'm using cache-view=true and it's not working :)

Comment: Please create plunker for that. Cache-view is working for me