# $ionicConfigProvider and cache-view="true" not working Ionic 1

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have **Three Tabs** on my screen and I am able to navigate to them:

- Tab1
- Tab2
- Tab3

I am fitching some data from `REST API` and I am displaying it on my screen with some Gauge. The data is successfully loaded, but when I navigate to any other Tab (`Tab2` or `Tab3`) and then coming back to `Tab1` my data isn't there. I want `Tab1` to be consistent and I want it as it as as I have left before going to any other Tab.

What I've done so far is:

- Adding **cache-view="true"**:

  `<ion-view view-title="Tab1" cache-view="true">`
- Adding **cache : true**:

  ```
  $stateProvider
  .state('tab', {
    url: '/tab',
    abstract: true,
    cache : true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
  })
  .state('tab.dash', {
    url: '/dash',
    cache : true,
    views: {
      'tab-dash': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/tab-dash.html',
      controller: 'DashCtrl'
    }
  }})
  ```
- **$ionicConfigProvider** from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38564639/5737774)

  ```
  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ionicConfigProvider) {
      $ionicConfigProvider.views.forwardCache(true);
      $ionicConfigProvider.views.maxCache(10);
  ```

But nothing worked for me.

**PS:** I am using *Ionic1* + *AngularJS*.